# setting the next tab sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which constitute of span as well as input. I want to set the tabindex of each element so for that I am using below code

```
var setTab = '#pg_' + strGridId.split('_')[0] + '_';

jQuery(setTab).find('span, input').each(function(index, elem) {
    jQuery(elem).attr('tabindex', tabIndex++);
});
```

Now, in my UI I have like span1, span2 input1 span3 input2. With above code tabindex is properly set for span i.e. if I press tab it goes to span1, span2 and then it goes to span3, missing input1 because input1 tabindex is more than span3.

can anyone please give me a suggestion on how I can achieve this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question? Where is `tabIndex` defined?

Comment: The order of the elements in a selector are arbitrary and cannot be guaranteed from browser to browser. If you have to loop through the elements in a specific order, you'll need to `sort()` them in the selector before you loop through them

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan _"The order of the elements in a selector are arbitrary"_ The elements should be in order of appearance in `document`, yes?

Comment: In theory, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What would be case when that would occur, other than user moving element to a different location in `document`, other than child node of `setTab`? `document.querySelectorAll()` returns elements in sequential order within parent selector, correct? Else `:nth-child()`, `:nth-of-type()` `css` selectors would not return accurate result?

Comment: I just realized if I use :input then it properly setting the tabindex for select field but why it is not setting for textbox?